# What caused the forks in the Schlesi testnet?

Tags: testnets, eth-2.0, lighthouse, prysm, teku

The Schlesi testnet was the first multiclient testnet for ETH2 clients.  Lighthouse, Prysm, Teku were in consensus before it forked.

What were the causes of the forks?  Is there a **technical** post mortem report on it?

[image: Schlesi fork]

[Source](https://twitter.com/a4fri/status/1261963932455100417)

Comment: This comment will be deleted.  "Technical" is bolded to minimize popular media reports that are incomplete or inaccurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What were the causes of the forks?

There were some issues relating to rewards/penalties calculation. Both Lighthouse and Prysm were incorrectly computing the validator balances.

Interestingly, Lighthouse, Prysm and ZCLI (reference spec implementation in Go) *all* computed different values, the result of multiple unrelated issues. Teku stayed faithful to the specification.

#### Client Fixes

- Lighthouse

  - https://github.com/sigp/lighthouse/pull/1166
- ZCLI

  - https://github.com/protolambda/zrnt/commit/ee4c8af2fb45301fdff6c7c72638e7ee677ec8fe
- Prysm

  - https://github.com/prysmaticlabs/prysm/pull/5909
  - https://github.com/prysmaticlabs/prysm/pull/5903

#### Steps taken to resolve:

- All clients have fixed the bug.
- The latest spec [`v0.12.0`](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/releases/tag/v0.12.0) has refactored balance calculations so they're easier to test. More tests have been added.
- The offending blocks and states have been added to [beacon-fuzz](https://github.com/sigp/beacon-fuzz) (eth2 fuzzer) to help protect against regression and find related bugs.

*Side note: this fork highlighted an interesting balance calculation quirk in the spec when the network isn't reaching finality. The specification was changed [here](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/pull/1830).*